# Clojure - Docjure: Method works in REPL but not in File

Tags: excel, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I just try to read the content of an excel file in clojure. I use the docjure library. When I use the sample code in the REPL, the output is as I wanted it. But after inserting it into the file I got an Wrong number of args - Error for the spreadsheet/select-sheet method.

Here is the code:

```
(use 'dk.ative.docjure.spreadsheet)

(->> (load-workbook (str (System/getProperty "user.dir") "/resources/public/xls/test.xls")
                    (select-sheet "menu")
                    (select-columns {:A :number, :D :name})
                    ))
```

The args for  this method are `[name ^Workbook workbook]`. Why does it only need one argument in the REPL but two in the file?

Comment: You've got your parens wrong in the threading macro. You need to pull the `select-sheet` and `select-columns` forms outside the `load-workbook` form. As written here, `(select-sheet "menu")` is going to be evaluated and passed as an arg to `load-workbook`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as *Alex* said in comments, you messed with parens.

Right now your code code evaluates into:

```clj
(load-workbook (str (System/getProperty "user.dir")
                    "/resources/public/xls/test.xls")
               (select-sheet "menu")
               (select-columns {:A :number, :D :name}))
```

Here is how your actual code should look like:

```
(->> "/resources/public/xls/test.xls"
     (str (System/getProperty "user.dir"))    ; prefix it with user.dir
     load-workbook                            ; load .xls workbook
     (select-sheet "menu")                    ; select menu sheet
     (select-columns {:A :number, :D :name})) ; select some columns
```

Which evaluates into:

```
(select-columns {:A :number, :D :name}
                (select-sheet "menu"
                              (load-workbook (str (System/getProperty "user.dir")
                                                  "/resources/public/xls/test.xls"))))
```

As you can see, both `select-sheet` and `select-columns` are called with two arguments here.

To better understand how thread-last macro `->>` works, [see its documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E%3E).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But why does it evaluate in the REPL?

Comment: @DanielderGrosse it shouldn't. Examine your REPL history, most likely your actual code looked differently. You just misplaced one of your parens, which is easy to miss.